# Python, PyTest is it possbile to add both long and short args?

Tags: python, pytest

Hello i'm trying to add args to my pytest tests I've tried something like

```
#conftest.py content
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("-t", "--test", action="store")
```

but this gives me:

> AttributeError: 'Argument' object has no attribute 'dest'

i rather not have to read -t and --test as separate args.

Comment: please, provide [mre] as well as full traceback you get.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you get this error message. If I do the same, I get:

```
ValueError: lowercase shortoptions reserved
```

meaning that `pytest` reserves all lower-case option abbreviations to itself, so it is not possible to do what you want. If you want to add an abbreviation, you have to use an upper case one instead:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("-T", "--test", action="store")
```

The error message

```
AttributeError: 'Argument' object has no attribute 'dest'
```

is actually shown if you use an invalid abbreviation (with more than one letter), for example:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("-tt", "--test", action="store")
```

The message is misleading - the actual error message is correct, but due to a glitch in the error handling in pytest the error is not propagated to the caller, and you get that message instead.

As to why you get this message - either your test was different from the one you have shown, or in your version of pytest the correct error (`lowercase shortoptions reserved`) is also incorrectly propagated.