# pytest get command line options

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I have couple of questions regarding commandline options of pytest

1. If it is possible to use long names and short names for the same option, for example

   parser.addoption('--server', '-srv', dest = 'SERVER')
2. How to access to commandline option by name, like :

   config.option.NAME

   ```
    def environment_options(parser):
        parser.addoption('--server', dest= "SERVER")

    @pytest.fixture()
    def enfironment_set_up():
        if config.option.SERVER == 'some value': 
           actions
   ```

pycharm shows reference unresolved 'config'. Do I need to import something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (haven't found that in the documentation), it is possible to add a short name, but only one with one upper case letter, e.g.:

```py
 def environment_options(parser):
     parser.addoption('-S', '--server', dest= "SERVER")
```

Lowercase letters are reserved for pytest itself, and longer abbreviations are not supported. See also my somewhat related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67244345/12480730).

You can access the option via `config` in the `request` fixture:

```py
 @pytest.fixture
 def enfironment_set_up(request):
     if request.config.getoption("SERVER") == 'some value': 
        actions
```